# Replace IKImageBrowserView's Superclass with NSVisualEffectView

Tags: macos, cocoa, subclass, ikimagebrowserview, nsvisualeffectview

I looking to make my IKImageBrowserView's background have a blurred background. According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/index.html), the IKImageBrowserView is based upon NSView. Is it possible to make an IKImageBrowserView inherit from an NSVisualEffectView instead so that I can give the background a blurred look. I assume that to start I must subclass the IKImageView, but I am unsure of where to go next. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the IKImageBrowserView as a **subview** for an NSVisualEffectsView and make sure the browser view doesn't draw it's background.

The visual effects views are intended to be used in this way, not through class inheritance.